# Can you use a motor to run a transformer?

Tags: transformer, dc-motor, high-voltage, low-voltage

I asked a similar question earlier where I was not very specific. Here is the improved question (I hope). Can I use a brushed d/c motor to power a transformer when the motor creates 0.5VAC when the shaft is spun? I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Exactly what @Russel said in his [comment](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/267979/can-you-use-a-motor-to-run-a-transformer#comment602453_267981) below: You're having a bad case of the [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and if you don't tell us what you want to achieve in the bigger picture, you probably won't get the help you need.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use a brushed d/c motor to power a transformer

A brushed DC motor produces DC and not AC. Therefore, the DC motor (when run as a generator) cannot produce 0.5 VAC or any other AC voltage. Transformers need AC to operate correctly so this idea sounds problematic.

Also, transformers are not "powered" as such - they take AC power in when the load demands that power (ignoring losses).

Comment: I also have a stepping motor. Will that work?

Comment: I don't know, I'm no expert on stepper motors but that sounds like a different question to me.

Comment: A stepper motor will produce typically a few volts AC when spun vigorously BUT the frequency varies with spin speed. what you **REALLY** want to do is to tell us what you actually want to achieve and not how you think you MIGHT achieve it. Generally better answers happen that way.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon [yep](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Are you happy with this answer? If so can you formally accept it. If not can you explain what you don't understand about my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A brushed motor can not be used as a small AC generator. There might be a simple solution for your problem. In the past you would find very small AC generators used on bicycles, They produce AC and generate 2 or 3 Watt power at a voltage of 6V.

A little remark. The frequency of an AC generator depends on it's speed. Therefore you have to verify if your transformer is able to handle the frequency comming from the bicycle generator. If an ordinary mains transformer gives problems you might try to use (again from the past) a transformer from an old audio amplifier.

Warning. Be carefull with high voltages when transforming. High voltages can kill. 
[image]